# How to enable non-const string literals in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In C++, having a string literal, as in this line of code:

```cpp
if(str_cmp(pair,"File Not Found")==0)
```

Visual Studio won't compile it:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *" ConsoleApplication1 prog2bas.cpp    498
```

But, on the command-line, it compiles perfectly (and works too, since I am not even trying to modify that):

`cl prog2bas.cpp /link:winscard.lib`

Why does the same thing work from the command line, but not from the GUI?

Is there some configuration to enable this setting?

FYI, the file is 100% compatible with C, where string literals are not const, but I am unable to compile it either, since it's using optional arguments with default values:

```c
char*   BCX_TmpStr(size_t,size_t= 128,int= 1);
```

They work in PCC and LCC, but not in MSVC.

If there is a way to enable optional args in MSVC, that could also be a good way out.

The file was generated with BCX basic.  I searched their Forum, but nothing mentioned there.  Has anyone used BCX output with VS successfully?

Comment: Can you not just change the function `str_cmp` to be const-correct?  Or compile with C instead of C++?

Comment: correct, but comes from BCX runtime, a TP library, better work around than hack

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are different languages. They should not be used interchangeably as there have different rules in many areas including this one.

Comment: when compiling as c i do have the issue with optional arguments `char*   BCX_TmpStr(size_t,size_t= 128,int= 1);` which seems to be cplusplusish, however in PCC it works

Comment: Okay, so the library generates invalid C++ code...  Fix it at the source.

Comment: You appear to be describing tools that were written about 20 years ago when the C++ language standards were either not well established, or not well supported.

Comment: If you are 100% sure that `str_cmp` doesn't try to change the C strings, you could just add an overload: `int str_cmp(const char* str1, const char* str2) { return str_cmp(const_cast<char*>(str1), const_cast<char*>(str2)); }` - If you are unsure, make copies of the strings and pass those to the old `str_cmp` ... or better: Change the `str_cmp` calls to use the standard `std::strcmp` instead.

Comment: Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > "Conformance mode" = No.

Comment: @HansPassant Your could make an answer out of your command and i will remove mine, and accept it, sorry i missed your comment while typing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all valuable input, I've managed to find the cause

CL doesn't use by default Conformance Mode

Visual Studio Projects have Conformance Mode enabled by default since latest versions.

See more on (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-160)

Comment: From command line, `/Zc:strictStrings` or `/permissive-` disallows conversion from `const char*` to `char*`